# Django 2 forms on 1 page,1 is ajax and 1 is not

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, forms, web

Using class based views, I can successfully process my normal form, my ajax form returns valid and all is well but I'm really struggling to figure out where I should be handling the ajax request, should I be doing it in get_context_data or in the form_valid method, in either case it doesn't process it correctly

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(POEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['document_header'] = self.object

    if self.request.POST:
        #Posted Form
        if self.request.is_ajax:
            self.get_ajax_response()
            context['form_comments'] = DocumentCommentsUpdateForm(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        context['form_lines'] = DocumentFormSetUpdate(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        #No Post
        context['form_lines'] = DocumentFormSetUpdate(instance=self.object)
        context['form_comments'] = DocumentCommentsUpdateForm()
        context['comments'] = self.get_comments()
    return context
```

get ajax response below, its entre

```
def get_ajax_response(self):
    data = {
        'pk': 'pk',
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

there is appropriate code to send and receive a response in the view

```
$('#comments-form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url : "{% url 'po:edit' document_header.id %}",
    type : "POST",
    data : serializedData,
    success : function(json) {
        $('#id_comment').val('');
        console.log(json);
        console.log("success");
    },
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>");
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your class hierarchy, I'd say you should override the `post()` method and neither the `get_context_data()` nor the `form_valid()` method.

Try something like the following (adapted from [this obsolete Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example)):

```
def post(self, request):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        data = {
            'pk': self.object.pk,
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return super().post(request)
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver! 
it was this line that did it:
return super().post(request)
 I tried before catching it at the post method but couldn't understand how I was meant to carry on with normal processing if it wasn't ajax!